# Why is it that the derivative of a function sometimes gives only one extremum (say, a point of minima but not maxima)?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I have solved several questions in which one is supposed to find the maximum and minimum value of function. I usually take the derivative and check but I've come across some functions which give only one point of extrema. In that case, I move on to the range method and I get the answer but however, I wonder why setting the derivative $= 0$ fails to give the points.

For example,

$$f(x)=(\arcsin x)³+(\arccos x)³,$$
$$x∈[-1,1].$$

Its derivative gave me $arcsin=\fracπ4$ only and not $-π\over 2$ but the function does attain its minimum and maximum at these points respectively.

Comment: $-\frac\pi2$ isn't even in the domain of $f$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm sorry, I meant to type in $arcsin$ and not $x$

Comment: Anyway, since what you did does not produce the expected results, I suggest you exhibit exactly what you did.

Comment: Are you asking why (in the general case of finding global extrema) you have to take the extra steps to check the endpoints of the range, since the derivative by itself does not tell you when those points are local extrema? Or are you disturbed specifically because you don't get $\arcsin(-\pi/2)$ from either the derivative test _or_ the endpoint test?

Comment: By the way, consider the function $f(x) = x^3$ for $x\in[-1,1].$ This has $f'(0) = 0$ but there is neither a minimum _nor_ a maximum (not even a local one) at $x=0.$ The derivative doesn't even give you _one_ extremum of $f(x).$

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you have done !

1. $f$ is not differentiable in $ \pm 1$.
2. I get for $x \in (-1,1)$:  $f'(x)=0 \iff x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: how do you get x=1/2? must it not be x=1/√2?

Comment: OOOPs. You are right. !